# How to convert non-numeric strings into integers in R

Tags: r, associative-array

I have a data frame where one column is a factor.
I want to map that column into integers.
For instance, in the example below,
I want to map `healthy` to the value `2`,
`sick` to the value `1`,
and `dead` to the value `0`.
In this example the order of the states is important,
because I want state 2 to be healthier than state 1,
and state 1 to be healthier than state 0.

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                day = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
                state = c('healthy', 'sick', 'sick', 'dead'))
  id day   state
1  1   1 healthy
2  1   2    sick
3  2   1    sick
4  2   2    dead
```

What is the easiest way to manipulate the data frame `x`
in order to get the following output data frame?

```
  id day   state state_int
1  1   1 healthy         2
2  1   2    sick         1
3  2   1    sick         1
4  2   2    dead         0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As factors are already stored as integers this is a simple oneliner. If you want a certain order use the `ordered` function. If the order is not important - as it very often is -, `as.numeric(x$state)` is all you need ! To answer your question with certain order required:

```
x$state_num <- as.numeric(ordered(x$state, levels = c("dead", "sick", "healthy"))) -1

  id day   state state_num
1  1   1 healthy         2
2  1   2    sick         1
3  2   1    sick         1
4  2   2    dead         0
```

Answer (score 3):

this should work for any random mapping you want to assign

```
 x <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),

                day = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
                state = c('healthy', 'sick', 'sick', 'dead'))


ids <- c(1 , 2 , 0)
names(ids) <- c('healthy' , 'sick' , 'dead') 
cbind(x , state_int = ids[as.character(x$state)])

#   id day   state      state_int
#1  1   1   healthy         1
#2  1   2    sick           2
#3  2   1    sick           2
#4  2   2    dead           0
```

Comment: `setNames(0:2,c("dead","sick","healthy"))[as.character(x$state)]` as a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
> x$state_int <- as.integer(factor(x$state))
> x
  id day   state state_int
1  1   1 healthy         2
2  1   2    sick         3
3  2   1    sick         3
4  2   2    dead         1
```

However, factor levels are sorted by name and beginning at 1, thus the numbers doesn't exactly match your original post.

If you really need the numbers to match, you can try explicitly naming the levels:

```
x$state_int <- as.integer(factor(x$state, levels=c('dead', 'sick', 'healthy'))) - 1
```